# Is it possible for an uncountable subset $S$ of $\Bbb R$ to satisfy $∂S = S$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is it possible for an uncountable subset $S$ of $\Bbb R$ to satisfy $∂S = S$?

Please shed some light to it. I am not getting any clue to it.

Comment: Cantor Set?${}$

Comment: Any closed set $S$ with empty interior will have $S=\partial S$. Try the Cantor set.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible. For example, the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) $C$ is uncountable and closed, but has empty interior so $\partial C = \overline{C}\setminus C^{\circ} = C\setminus\emptyset = C$.

Comment: is it the only set enjoying this property??

Comment: No. Any uncountable closed set with empty interior will work. For example, $C\cup F$ for any finite set $F$.

Comment: Moreover, there are lots of different Cantor-type sets.